# Strange Bug in Chrome 69.0.3497.81 + spring boot security + vaadin when uploading files

Tags: google-chrome, spring-boot, vaadin8

I have a strange bug in my app when using Chrome 69.0.3497.81. The app works fine with previous versions of Chrome, as well as the latest Firefox, Opera and Edge.

The web-app is a Spring Boot application with Spring Boot Security (2.0.4) combined with Vaadin (8.5.1)

I have made a minimal project that exhibits the bug that can be found in https://github.com/npetalid/chromebug.git

The app shows a page with 6 buttons that upload a file. The buttons are identical. The 6th button you press (order does not play any role) fails. It waits for an answer from the server that never comes.

Uploading using the same button many times, is not a problem.

The bug only appears when spring boot security is on. I tried it on Chrome on Windows 10 and MacOs High Sierra.

As this bug is a combination of Chrome, Spring Boot Security and Vaadin I have no idea where else to ask, and thus I am asking the group here. If you feel that the question should be posted elsewhere, let me know

Comment: First thing that pops into my mind is that for some reason Spring Security creates new http session for each authorized upload, and you will run out maximum number of parallel supported http sessions with Chrome browser. See info here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-session how to change http session creation settings and here about http connection limits https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser

Comment: Hmmm I ll try it but how that would explain the fact that it works on all browsers except from Chrome 69?

Comment: Unfortunatelly, this is not it. I tried with more STATELESS and NEVER as far as the settings of http session creation, but behaviour remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed recently with Chrome my Spring Boot app (with security) that when mapping the method is executed twice. Testing it in Safari results in only a the expected single execution.

Comment: Your contirubution does not sound like an answer. (On the other hand the question does not contain a question mark.) Please be aware that stack overflow is not a forum. Maybe you can improve you answer. An anwer should show an approach to solve the questioner's problem.

Comment: I can' t comment on the original post because I'm a noob but wanted to comment so...

Answer (score 0):

Newest Chrome (70.0.3538.77 ) does not exhibit this behaviour, so the problem has solved itself! As far as I could see the browser opened 6 concurrent connections that were never closed. As for why this happened, I do not know. I suspect it was a bug that was corrected by the Chromium team.